# Passing a stream to a bash function

Tags: bash

I need to create a `bash` function that I can pass a stream to NOT A FILE. Here is the function:

```
ff() { cat /etc/group | fgrep -f "$1" ;}
```

When I run it like so:

```
ff <( echo some_user )
```

I get an error saying:

```
fgrep: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

instead of:

```
some_user:x:0:
```

Comment: you *must* precede the close brace with a newline or semicolon: `ff() { cat /etc/group | fgrep -f "$1"; }`-- see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: I am surprised the process substitution does not work.

Comment: The file get passed, but does not survive the pipe inside function. Try: `$ ff() { ls -l "$1"; printf "$1\n-----\n"; ls -l /dev/fd/; file "$1"; echo "----- Now for the pipe -----"; echo | file "$1"; ls -l /dev/fd/; cat "$1"; };  ff <(echo foo);`

Comment: I see what you mean, any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: @user1960118 - the pipeline spawns a subshell. Try `fgrep -f "$1" /etc/group` without the UUOC.

Comment: @Sukminder (and jordanm) Please make your comment an answer so that (a) you get your points and (b) this question can be marked answered.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Thanks. But was not sure *why* it got closed and thus I felt it was not not eligible as an answer – but probable as *information*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That'd be a bug or limitation in `bash`. Somehow, `bash` closes the file descriptor 63 which was the reading end of the pipe which `echo` is writing to before executing `fgrep`.

`zsh` or `ksh93` don't have that limitation.

In this very case you don't need the two processes anyway:

```
ff() { fgrep -f "$1" < /etc/group; }
```

In the general case, you can either use another shell or work around the `bash` limitation with:

```
ff() { sh -c 'cat /etc/group | fgrep -f "$1"' sh "$1";}
```

Or:

```
ff() { cat /etc/group | fgrep -f /dev/fd/3;} 3<"$1"
```